# Ant JUnit Error No runnable method. initializationError

Tags: java, ant, junit, junit4

We are getting this error, about which much has been written, from running JUnit via Ant.  We double checked all the advice we saw in the previous questions about this error, and it seems that we got everything we need in our test class, a public no-arg constructor and a single method with the `@Test` annotation!

```
Testsuite: sim.V
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec

Testcase: initializationError took 0.002 sec
    Caused an ERROR
No runnable methods
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)


Testsuite: simvim
```

Here is our Ant build XML file:

```
<target name="junit" depends="build">
  <junit fork="no" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
     <test name="sim.V" outfile="TB" />
     <formatter usefile="true" type="plain"/>
     <classpath>
       <pathelement path="/afs/cad.njit.edu/u/j/g/jg284/libs/junit.jar"/>
       <pathelement path="/afs/cad.njit.edu/u/j/g/jg284/libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>

        </classpath>
  </junit>
</target>
```

Here is our test class:

```
package sim;
import java.io.*;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class V {
  public V() {
  }

  @Test
  public void SG() throws IOException,sim.SE,Exception {
    Simulation S = new Simulation();
    S.logger = Simulate.createLogger("log.out","FINEST", false);
    S.stat = Simulate.createLogger("logstat.out","FINEST", false);
    sim.movers.SMover SM = new sim.movers.SMover(S);
    SM.TB();
  }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: use standard Java naming conventions. ClassesAreNamedLikeThis variablesAreNamedLikeThis soAreFields andMethods

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `fork="yes"` instead of `fork="no"`.  I was able to reproduce your problem with `fork="no"` but not with `fork="yes"`.

I can't tell you why it doesn't work with `fork="no"`.  I would guess at some kind of class-loading issue with Ant.   I spent some time Googling but all I could find was [a bug from 2006](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40697) (which I'm not sure is related as I don't have `junit4.jar` in `ANT_HOME/lib`), and a [blog post](http://toddgerspacher.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/apache-ant-vs-gradle-junit.html) from last July, whose author mentions that:

> Note: If you forget to set the fork attribute to true, you'll get an error message similar to the following:
>   *(error message similar to yours omitted)*